# how to make material side nav display on all page

Tags: angular, angular-material, sidenav

I have created material side nav and added it to my app but it doesn't work properly. Where do I need to put the nav component?

I want to replace the horizontal nav of my app with side nav, I have used material side nav. When I click the button to open the menu, logic doesn't work on all components even if I implement the nav in the app component. How can I fix the visibility?

This is my menu component:

```
<mat-drawer-container class="container" autosize>
  <mat-drawer #drawer class="sidenav">
      <!-- <p>Menu</p> -->
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" (click)="onSelect($event.target.text)">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" (click)="onSelect($event.target.text)">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" (click)="onSelect($event.target.text)">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
  </mat-drawer>
  <div class="sidenav-content">
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="drawer.toggle()">
          <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
  </div>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

This is my app component:

```
[<main>  
    <app-menu (pageSelected)="onNavigate($event)"></app-menu> 
    <app-header></app-header>
    <app-home *ngIf="loadedPage === 'Home'"></app-home>
    <app-cards-body *ngIf="loadedPage === 'Products'"></app-cards-body>
    <app-about *ngIf="loadedPage === 'About'"></app-about>
</main>][1]
```

The menu opens properly but does not cover the entire page.
If I place the menu in above the other components at the app component I get a blank page but without any errors:

Image 1:

[image]

Image 2:

[image]

Image 3:

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't be displaying components via *ngIfs, you should be using routing.

Regardless, the `<mat-drawer-container>` belongs in your `app.component.html`, not `main-menu.html`

Answer (score 0):

The `AppComponent` should contain the high-level scaffolding for the app, such as the `sidenav` or `drawer` component.

## app.component.html

```
<mat-drawer-container class="container">
  <mat-drawer #drawer mode="side" opened>
    <!-- <p>Menu</p> -->
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" (click)="onSelect($event.target.text)">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" (click)="onSelect($event.target.text)">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" (click)="onSelect($event.target.text)">Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </mat-drawer>

  <mat-drawer-content>
    <app-header></app-header>
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="drawer.toggle()">
      <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </mat-drawer-content>
</mat-drawer-container>
```